# QGIS Processing Modeller - Select date by expression

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, expression, extract

I have a data file that contains current meter data for multiple days.

I am trying to use the Processing Modeller to extract a single days worth of data for further manipulation, using the `Extract by Expression` algorithm.

My input data layer has the date in it, with the format `dd/mm/yy` (i.e 01/12/19)
[image]

I've tested my selection expression using Select by expression in QGIS as per below, which correctly selects 1 days worth of data.[image]

Building my model, I select the input later using a vector feature parameter definition.  I then used String parameter definition to input the required date `'25/12/19'` and the date field `"%Date"`

[image][image]

I entered the below expression into the Processing Modeller to match the `Select by Expression` that I tested ealier.
[image]

When I run the model, nothing is extracted to the result layer.

I'm sure it's probably a syntax problem, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Note that `'25/12/19'` is not a date. It is a string representing a date. A date would be `2019-12-25`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect its checking the literal value of the `DateField` Input against the literal value of the `EnterDate` input. In other words, its not extracting the value of the field named by the value of `DateField`. This looks like too many levels of indirection.

You probably need to use the `attribute` function to get the value of an attribute in a layer by a variable holding the name of the field. After a few tests I've got this to work:

```
 attribute(@datefield) = @enterdate
```

*BUT* you don't put the field name in quotes in the Input - just `%Date`, not `"%Date"` as you had. (Note I did everything in `lowercase` but that's not totally necessary)

To test it, I used the Field Calculator algorithm to create a new layer so I could see what the expression engine was computing for each part of the expression. After about 50 iterations of various attempts I think I've got it...

Comment: Hi Spacedman

You were correct.  When i tried your suggestion, I got the data output that I wanted.

Thank you for your time in helping me get this sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I use QGIS 3.16.10. The function "Select by expression" works very well outside the modeler. But, it didn't work in modeler. I ended up switching to a more straightforward tool -- the "Select by attributes".